# What's the difference between the $rootScope and value-service in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS you can store data in the $rootScope or create a value-Service?
Both of them you can only access with the dependency injection - so where's the difference?
When should I use the $rootScope and when the value-Service?

Answer (score 0):

`$rootScope` is the root `scope` object, it is the parent object that all other `scope` inherit from.  When a property is added to `$rootScope`, that property is available to all descendent `$scope` objects.  These properties are present, even if `$rootScope` is not injected into the controller, but injection is necessary in order to programmatically modify the properties.  Also, due to [JavaScript prototype inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) rules, it is potentially possible for a specific controller to *hide* a `$rootScope` value. This makes `$rootScope` a *pseudo global*, and potentially unsafe.  However, due to the fact that every `scope` is a descendent of `$rootScope`, `$rootScope` is ideal for things like `$broadcast`.

A `Value` service is a simple injectable singleton value.  It is *never* available unless injected. A `Value` is not intended to be modified directly, however it is *possible* to do so in Angular 1.x.  `Value` can also be intercepted by a `Decorator`.